# Django 1.7 admin allow_tags issue

Tags: django, django-templates, widget, breadcrumbs

I am building a quiz application and I have a Question model.  I want to allow the Question model to handle html tags. By using change_form.html and specifying {{ content|safe }} I was able to allow the add and edit Question pages to render the html tags. In my model I created a custom field that had allow_tags set to True which enabled me to render the Question correctly on the admin list pages. The issue now I am facing is that the breadcrumbs that appear in the admin and also the Recent Activity Widget on the dashboard shows questions and its showing away the html tags. How can I override these to handle the html tags ?